# PDF print on dot matrix printer

Tags: dot-matrix-printer

I have installed one new dot matrix printer in our office normal prints are working fine but PDF print are not clear ? Is there any way to print PDF on dot matrix printer?

Comment: A dot matrix printer can print graphics (which is what a PDF is in this respect), but you need to have a suitable driver for this to work. Expect the output to be slow, noisy and prone to consume the (color/monchrome) ink-ribbon quickly. This may also depend a lot on the brand and model of your printer.

Comment: In line with Hannu's advice, try printing an image to get an idea of what the printer is capable of.  Dot matrix printers generally suck at images; there isn't enough resolution to do a good job.  You may need to turn the PDF output to text (which might require conversion or OCR).